# Why is my Codename One Project "not a visual project type"?

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea, codenameone

Newbie Codename One user here. I am using Intellij Idea. Whenever I open up theme.res and try to create a new GUI by clicking "Add a New GUI Element", I get a popup dialog that says "Notice, this is not a visual project type". When I close the dialog, the new GUI element appears in the list, but there's no options to edit it. Did I miss a step somewhere that caused my project to be incompatible?

Answer (score 1):

This is the "old" GUI builder see [this](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/using-the-new-gui-builder.html).

Regular projects work just fine with the new GUI builder. With the old GUI builder you need to use a specific project structure when you create a project initially. We term this as a "visual" project which might be confusing, since we are phasing out the old GUI builder we might review the terminology here.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Yeah, changing the dialog message might keep idiots like me from struggling with that.

Comment: @BrentW. Yes, I agree. I haven't played with Codename One for several months and it seems like this change must have taken place in the meantime. I would not have figured this out if not for this thread. I think a lot of people who know about this plugin probably picked it up from the Coursera course that covers it. Do you know if that is being updated for the new GUI builder?

Comment: Yes the course is being updated to the new GUI builder